# Can you see an image created by projector with bare eyes?

Tags: optics

The question is as simple as I described in the title. Can you see an image created by a projector with your bare eyes? If so, where should you stand with respect to projector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't try this because the light will be too bright to be safe for your eyes.**

The projector works by focusing an image onto the screen. If you remove the screen, then the image still exists that you can view if you are situated where the light can reach your eyes. The screen normally reflects that light to your eyes. **If you remove the screen and stand behind where the screen normally sits you will be able to see the image, but you will only see a very small portion of the image.** The only light visible to you would be coming directly from the projector lens, so you'd be viewing a very small portion of the total image. You could test this by putting a very very small figure at the center of your slide, stand directly behind where the image would normally form on the screen, and focus your eyes to where you would normally see it if a semi-transluscent screen was between you and the projector. Again, take my word for this and don't try it unless you don't care about damaging your eyes. Alternatively, you could try using a magnifying lens and object situated as in the ray diagram below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought I accepted your answer, sorry for the latency. Have a good day!